# How can I match the lowercase version of a backreference

Tags: regex, grep

I'd like to match the lowercase version of an uppercase character in a backreference in a regex. For example, let's say I want to match a string where the 1st character is any uppercase character and the 4th character is the same letter as the first except it's a lowercase character. If I use `grep` with this regex:

```
grep -E "([A-Z])[a-z]{2}\1[a-z]"
```

it would match `"EssEx"` and `"SusSe"` for instance. I'd like to match `"Essex"` and `"Susse"` instead. Is it possible to modify the above regular expression to achieve this ?

Comment: Well, try `"[A-Z][a-z]{4}"`

Comment: That would also match "Esssx" for example. I only want it to match if it's a lower case version of the same letter that's in the backreference. E.g `a` for `A`, `q` for `Q`. Not any other lowercase character.

Comment: Are inline modifiers supported? If yes, good old `([A-Z])[a-z]{2}(?-i)(?!\1)(?i)\1[a-z]*` should work.

Comment: @SebastianProske that works as expected if I use `grep -P` which is fine. If you post an answer with this I'll accept it because it uses grep and is slightly simpler/shorter than @anubhava's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of the cases where inline modifiers come in handy. Here is a solution that makes use of a case-senstive lookahead to check, that it is not exactly the same (uppercase) character and a case-insensitive backreference to match the fitting lowercase letter:

```
([A-Z])[a-z]{2}(?-i)(?!\1)(?i)\1[a-z]
```

Note that the (?-i) most likely isn't needed, but it's there for clarity. Inline modifiers are not supported by all regex flavours. PCRE supports it, so you will have to use `-P` with grep.

Answer (score 2):

It will be more verbose but this [awk](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html) does the job:

```
awk '/([A-Z])[a-z]{2}/ && tolower(substr($1, 1, 1)) == substr($1, 4, 1) && 
     substr($1, 5) ~ /[a-z]/' file

Essex
Susse
```

Comment: I've not seen you here for ages then, bam, you come along and shine a light for us mere mortals!